# Compactness in Sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, sobolev-spaces

I am looking for characterizations of compactness in the Sobolev space $H^{-1}$. 
In particular, I am looking for a characterization involving the Fourier transform.

Can anyone suggest some results or where to find them?

Thank you very much in advance!